# How to determine where the cold is coming from?

Tags: doors

My new home has a door which is very tired and allows cold in some how.

I have tried to work out how the cold is getting in, but it seems to be getting in throughout the entire door.

I was expecting it to be the seal or the letter box, but i can't tell.

How can i check if we need a new door, new seal, or new letter box etc?

Answer (score 1):

Checking first to eliminate gaps hidden behind the doors' trim or molding is the place to begin. Expanding foam or pieces of rolled insulation work well to stop drafts.   If your door is mostly wood (as most are) it could be that the cold outside air is being conducted through the door. Installing an exterior second "storm door" would provide an air space and a thermal break from the frigid exterior air. This should solve any drafts that are allowing cold air to penetrate through to the living space. here is a link to a door [door](http://www.lowes.com/pd_16074-62847-59008031M_1z0x51o__?productId=50374530&pl=1)

Comment: I'm from the UK and i have never seen a 'storm' door. Can you explain what that is please?

Comment: It is a lightweight door, usually built with an extruded aluminum or roll-formed steel frame, or wood. They are frequently mounted on the outside or distal part of the main door jamb, or sometimes surface mounted over the door opening. They often have glass or clear plastic panels. Basically, it's like a screen door but sturdier and with solid translucent panels.

Comment: a storm door is a secondary aluminum or wood door that is attached so that is covering the existing door. It is framed such that it is secured to the wall by means of a simple "L"- shaped frame. http://www.lowes.com/pd_16074-62847-59008031M_1z0x51o__?productId=50374530&pl=1